# Load OpenSSL API code Apache

Tags: c++, c, apache, openssl

Is posible to load a custom module, or patch based on OpenSSL API to an Apache reverse proxy using C/C++ ???.

I can build a `.so` object using OpenSSL API and preload it to some TLS clients (like wget) but I dont know how to do that on an Apache server.

Any idea?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own OpenSSL libraries libssl.so and libcrypto.so. Then you need to specify those libs in the `LD_PRELOAD=` variable of your apache process environment (see more about LD_PRELOAD [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230/what-is-the-ld-preload-trick))

Comment: I'm currently doing that on client to add some custom extension to the client hello, but how can I use it on Apache?? can I do it with apache process environment variables ????

Comment: Depending on your OS, you need to modify the apache start script (init.d) or the systemd conf file.

Comment: Maybe something like that... [crypto_example_ld_preload](http://www.security-projects.com/?libCryptoLog___Apache_example). THXS ALL DUDES.